# $_GET Not working with include virtual. PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, include, get

How can I make GET requests to work if my website is built on includes?

for example in index.html I rely on `<!--#include virtual="/includes/columns/col-2.shtml" -->` to show the content.

And in `col-2.shtml` I got this simple script `<?php $success = $_GET['success']; if($success == 1) { echo "User created!"; }?>`

So when I browse to http://www.mysite.com/index.html?success=1 It doesn't display my echo. And yes .shtml is set to parse php in .htaccess.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. Does the apache virtual process processed PHP actually when bound to .shtml?

Comment: View source when you goto that page - you'll probably find your <?php tags are showing, but not being rendered by the browser!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing your technologies here!!!

Rename index.html to index.php (or index.shtml), and change your include to be

```
<?php 
include('/includes/columns/col-2.shtml');
?>
```

Comment: @David Meyer: That's what testing servers are for.

Comment: don't preview in dreamweaver.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a limitation of Dreamweaver!  shtml includes are not meant to include PHP files. This is why something's going wrong (I'm presuming it not being parsed as PHP correctly) and it's not being passed the GET.  It's your choice which is more important - the data getting through, or your Preview working :(

Answer (score 0):

Includes don't naturally send GET/POST info... You can try this:

```
<?
$_POST[username]="123456";
include("login.php");
?>
```